# Boolean variable with True value does not go into the correct "if (variable)" condition but goes to a condition of "not (variable)"

Tags: python, boolean

I made a function that when returns True, I placed that True value into a variable and put that variable in a if condition, It goes to the other condition with the `elif not`, when I tried printing it, It prints it once as True and once at False, With only one print line.

Why does it change values, And how do I fix it?
Edit: deleted the last part of the output because it comes from a print outside the function where this happens, the True and False now come merely from the one print line. the "X" and sorted list are not a part of the problem, Just the print and the if conditions

Code:

```
# letter_guessed = "s", old _letters_guessed = [] (empty list)

is_valid = check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed) # is_valid = True
print(is_valid) 
if(is_valid): # skips this
    old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
    return True
elif not(is_valid): # enters this
    sorted_list = " -> ".join(old_letters_guessed)
    print("X")
    print(sorted_list)
    return False
```

Output:

## Both True and False come from the same print line, There isn't another print

```
True
False
```

Comment: Print-debugging is a horrible waste of your time. You'd be better suited to learn how to use the debugger, which would find your issue in an instant.

Comment: From where does the last print come from? If you missed that then you probably missed some other print as well.

Comment: For one, notice there's two booleans printed before "X", yet your code has only one print statement prior to `print("X")`, and the most proximal one is `print(is_valid) `. Clearly, `is_valid` is `False`. Between the hypothesis that if/else is broken in python, and the hypothesis `is_valid` having a value that defeats your expectations, the latter is the case, every time.

Comment: To add to my last comment, I'm pretty sure you printed in check_valid_input which was True, but it actually returns False by the time it is done. The second print is actually print(is_valid) that we see in the code, which is False.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on some of the comments. Your function check_valid_input seems to be printing a boolean value as well. That is the only explanation as to why there are two Booleans being printed. In the example you gave, is_valid is False.

```py
letter_guessed = "s", 

old_letters_guessed = [] 

is_valid =  False
print(is_valid) 
def f():
    if(is_valid): # skips this
        old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
        return True
    else: # enters this
        sorted_list = " -> ".join(old_letters_guessed)
        print("X")
        print(sorted_list)
        return False

f()
```

This works as expected.